# Turn a flat table into a tree with QIdentityProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt

I want to write a proxy model that groups a flat table into a tree by the first (n) columns, similar to [this UI library for React](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/grouping/).

I am struggling to get this to work, even in its simplest form:
[image]

First question is: *do i need to implement all four of the following or only `mapToSource` and `mapFromSource`?*

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qidentityproxymodel.html#parent
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qidentityproxymodel.html#index
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qidentityproxymodel.html#mapToSource
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qidentityproxymodel.html#mapFromSource

If so, how can I achieve the behavior with the following code? I am trying around but I always come up with deadlocks or weird behavior.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QIdentityProxyModel>


class GroupByFirstColumnProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GroupByFirstColumnProxyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QIdentityProxyModel{parent}  {}

    ~GroupByFirstColumnProxyModel() {}

    void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* sourceModel) override {
        return QIdentityProxyModel::setSourceModel(sourceModel);
    }

    int columnCount (const QModelIndex &parent=QModelIndex()) const override {
        auto cols = QIdentityProxyModel::columnCount(parent);
        qDebug() << "columnCount" << parent << cols << parent.isValid();
        return cols;
    }

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
        qDebug() << "index" << row << column << parent;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::index(row, column, parent);
    }

    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const override {
        if (!child.isValid()) {
            return QModelIndex();
        }
        qDebug() << "parent" << child;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::parent(child);
    }

    QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const override {
        qDebug() << "mapFromSource" << sourceIndex;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(sourceIndex);
    }

    QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const override {
        if (!proxyIndex.isValid()) {
            return QModelIndex();
        }
        qDebug() << "mapToSource" << proxyIndex;
        return QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(proxyIndex);
    }
};

static bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if (!db.open()) {
        return false;
    }
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("create table simple (A int, B int)");
    query.exec("insert into simple values(1, 2)");
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    if (!createConnection())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel;
    model->setTable("simple");
    model->select();

    QTreeView *view = new QTreeView;


    GroupByFirstColumnProxyModel *proxy = new GroupByFirstColumnProxyModel;

    proxy->setSourceModel(model);

    view->setModel(proxy);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: No idea about this library, but from looking at the documentation I wonder why you are inheriting from `QIdentityProxyModel` which is a concrete class, instead of from the abstract class `QAbstractProxyModel`.

Comment: I've seen comparable problems where `QIdentityProxyModel` was suggested for convenience (can't find any right now). Of course I'm open to solutions using `QAbstractProxyModel`. The library just shall give an example of the desired behavior.

Comment: Came to mind where I've seen solutions for similar problems using `QIdentityProxyModel`. [KDE](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kitemmodels/-/tree/master/src/core) uses it, for example

Comment: Please bear in mind that I have no idea about this library. However, from the `QIdentityProxyModel` documentation *QIdentityProxyModel can be used to forward the structure of a source model exactly, with no sorting, filtering or other transformation*. Is that the case for you? It seems to be, from what you are saying above, that a transformation is exactly what you are doing. But again I'm speaking from a position of ignorance.

Comment: The library shall just indicate the expected behavior, you can safely ignore it. KDE also subclasses  `QIdentityProxyModel` for rearranging columns, adding columns and other transformations (see https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kitemmodels/-/blob/master/src/core/kextracolumnsproxymodel.h)